"be distributed on" vs "be distributed in"

The books were distributed in various schools across the city.


The posters were distributed on bulletin boards around the campus.


The tasks were distributed on different days of the week.

what's the difference between "be distributed on" and  "be distributed in"? When to use "in" or "on"?

Most of the examples are not really to do with "distributed". Books are "in" schools, posters are "on" bulletin boards, etc.

Using "distributed across" might work in some of these examples

We always use on with days of the week. The books could have been distributed to schools if a consignment was sent to each school, or distributed in schools if a book was given to each pupil.

Think: [1] Where were the books distributed? // [2] Where were the posters posted? // [3] When / At what times were the tasks handed out? The preposition used in your answer will belong in the original sentence each time.

..distributed on different days of the week... Or were they all distributed at once? A better expession might be ...allotted/assigned TO different days of the week...
